# Video.js showing strange text before video loads

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I'm using Video.js v4.11.4

The text I'm referring to:
[image]

It disappears after the video loads, but I don't want it to appear at all. Any clue how to prevent this behavior?

Here's my configuration:

[image]
[image]

Comment: what templating system are you using?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC. It renders correct video resource URLs, no problem there. This is something about the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `preload: 'auto'` to `preload: 'none'`.

When set to auto, it will display video parameters. Set it to none and it should work fine.

This is what is given in the documentation of videojs: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/options.md

Comment: I'm reading the description of that option value and it sounds both unrelated and undesired:  "preload: 'none': Don't preload any of the video data. This will wait until the user clicks play to begin downloading."

Comment: I can see that the issue might lie with the control bar. This is the css class `vjs-control-bar`. Maybe hiding it via CSS might do the trick. Let me know if that works. I am unable to do that on the website directly.